# How to interpret mle() trace = 6 output and why does the mle() procedure stop after 101 iterations in R?

Tags: r, optimization, trace, mle, log-likelihood

I am trying to estimate seven constrained parameters with the function mle() using the L-BFGS-B method in R. In order to investigate why I get an `non-finite finite-difference value [2]` error, I include `control = list(trace = 6)` in the mle() function to hopefully learn more about the origins of the error.

I do not understand the output of the tracing very well unfortunately, making the result surprising to me: the program seems to simply stop after 101 iterations without giving me a proper reason.

Does anyone know why?

I suppose the seven X values reported by trace=6 are the parameter values the mle procedure has converged to up to this iteration. Imputing these values in my loglikelihood function gives me the same value as reported under "final value": -152.449285. When I impute the seven X values from iteration 97 I get the same loglikelihood of -152.449285.

There are two things that seem to stand out. First, the second value of X, 0.999, is exactly the upper limit of the second parameter I estimate. Second, the second value of G seems relatively large at -412.172 compared to the other G values. What exactly does G indicate? The second values of X and G have been like this for many iterations. Does any of this give me a clue how I can potentially make the estimation work? Thanks in advance!

Since my question is about interpretation/intuition of results I refrained from providing a reproducible example. Its lots of code and I do not know how to reproduce this situation with just a tiny bit of code. Please let me know if you need my code.

The final 101th iteration:

```
---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 4  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -9.1069e-03  3.1139e+01

Distance to the next break point =   1.9816e+00

Distance to the stationary point =   2.9246e-04

GCP found in this segment

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -9.1069e-03  3.1139e+01

Distance to the stationary point =   2.9246e-04

Cauchy X =  -0.749937 0.999 0.841376 1.14695 0.134673 0.121755 0.365289 


---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

0 variables leave; 0 variables enter

6  variables are free at GCP on iteration 101

LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 0.000232633

X = -0.749896 **0.999** 0.841349 1.14697 0.134672 0.121757 0.36551 

G = -0.0154393 **-412.172** -0.0621798 0.0130552 -0.00801055 0.00692317 -0.0134718 

final  value -152.449285 

**stopped after 101 iterations**

Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]
```

---- UPDATE 1 ---

I followed Roland's suggestion but first tried to set maxit at 200: `control = list(maxit=200, trace=6)`.

The procedure now converges at the 106th iteration, yet, I still get the error from before:

```
iterations 106
function evaluations 127
segments explored during Cauchy searches 110
BFGS updates skipped 2
active bounds at final generalized Cauchy point 1
norm of the final projected gradient 0.0217961
final function value -152.449

X = -0.749748 0.999 0.841415 1.14687 0.134666 0.121766 0.366383 

F = -152.449

final  value -152.449295 

converged

Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]
```

---- UPDATE 2---

I followed the suggestion by Biswajit Banerjee [optim in r :non finite finite difference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361821/optim-in-r-non-finite-finite-difference-error) and set ndeps which `?optim` tells me is "A vector of step sizes for the finite-difference approximation to the gradient" to 0.0001 for the second parameter (default 0.001 for all other parameters). Everything works fine now! I wonder whether this is related to the second parameter's value being the upper limit or its G value being relatively large?

Comment: `mle` uses `optim` and there the default is a maximum of 100 iterations. I'm only a bit confused because you get 101 iterations.

Comment: Can't test without reproducible example but have you tried `control = list(trace = 6, maxit = 500)`?