# Trying to make an optimizing for loglikelihood - having the error : initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite > ?vmmin

Tags: r, optimization

I am new in R and econometrics and run intro a problem while doing a task,

I am working on an ordered logit model where the log likelihood function needs to be optimized. I have tried various optimization methods in R, such as BFGS, L-BFGS-B, Newton-Raphson, and others. However, in each attempt, I receive the error message:

Error in optim(par = ..., fn = ..., method = ..., ...) : L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Initially, I tried optimizing the log likelihood function using the BFGS method, but it resulted in the mentioned error.

I experimented with different starting values for the optimization parameters, but the issue persisted. For instance, I tried using starting values like c(0, 0, 0, 0) and c(1, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5).

I also considered the possibility of data-related issues but couldn't identify any specific problems with the dataset.

Attempted to implement a bisection model and Newton-Raphson, but encountered similar issues and warnings about NaNs in the log probabilities.

i will leave here also the code

```
# Define the log likelihood function for the logistic distribution
loglikelihood <- function(par, z) {
  # Extract parameters from the parameter vector
  beta <- par[1]
  alpha <- par[2:4]
  
  # Extract variables from the data frame
  poss <- z[, 1]
  quartile <- z[, 2]
  
  # Calculate probabilities for each quartile
  prob1 <- exp(alpha[1] - poss * beta) / (1 + exp(alpha[1] - poss * beta))
  prob2 <- exp(alpha[2] - poss * beta) / (1 + exp(alpha[2] - poss * beta)) - prob1
  prob3 <- exp(alpha[3] - poss * beta) / (1 + exp(alpha[3] - poss * beta)) - exp(alpha[2] - poss * beta) / (1 + exp(alpha[2] - poss * beta))
  prob4 <- 1 - exp(alpha[3] - poss * beta) / (1 + exp(alpha[3] - poss * beta))
  
  # Combine probabilities based on observed quartile
  probabilities <- ifelse(quartile == 1, prob1,
                          ifelse(quartile == 2, prob2,
                                 ifelse(quartile == 3, prob3, prob4)))
  
  # Calculate the log likelihood by summing the log of probabilities
  ll <- sum(log(probabilities))
  
  # Return the negative log likelihood (to be minimized)
  return(-ll)
}

# Test the log likelihood function with initial parameter values
ll <- loglikelihood(par = c(0, 0, 0, 0), z = table)
print(ll)


p0 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0)
MLE <- optim(par = p0, fn = loglikelihood, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE, control = list(fnscale = -1), z = table)
print(MLE)`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you consider this post seeming to address a similar mle optimization? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361821/optim-in-r-non-finite-finite-difference-error?rq=2

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately we probably can't troubleshoot this without a [mcve], i.e. the results of `dput(table)` ...